Headless Chrome is not seeng that I am logged in to a site
Currently when I use headless chrome (chrome --headless --dump-dom) to get the contents of sites that require login (but keep you logged in), I always get a redirect to the contents of the registration/login page, whereas with the GUI I get the expected content.
I've tried adding the --user-agent, --profile-directory, --enable-features=NetworkService, --user-data-dir and --login-user switches in various combinations, all to no avail. How can I get headless chrome to see what the GUI sees?

What are you actually trying to do?  And how is this about programming?
